# How can i skip first nth documents in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on pagination in vue and firebase and it is working fine. But now i want to go directly to the nth page using pagination. But firebase doesn't allow me to do that. Please guide me on how can fix this.
[image]

```
onMounted(() => {
  totalLength()
  if (lastDoc.value && currentPosition.value == 'next') {
    next()
  } else if (lastDoc.value && currentPosition.value == 'prev') {
    prev()
  } else {
    loadPapers()
  }
})

const next = () => {
  savedTopifyPapers
    .orderBy('timeStamp', 'asc')
    .startAfter(lastDoc.value)
    .limit(1)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      lastDoc.value = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        loadingData.value = false
      }
      papersData.value = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data()
        const id = doc.id
        loadingData.value = false
        return { id, ...data }
      })
      papersDataLength.value = papersData.value.length
    })
}

const prev = () => {
  savedTopifyPapers
    .orderBy('timeStamp', 'asc')
    .endBefore(lastDoc.value)
    .limit(1)
    .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      lastDoc.value = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
      if (snapshot.empty) {
        loadingData.value = false
      }
      papersData.value = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data()
        const id = doc.id
        loadingData.value = false
        return { id, ...data }
      })
      papersDataLength.value = papersData.value.length
    })
}

const totalLength = () => {
  savedTopifyPapers.get().then((response) => {
    totalPaperLength.value = response.docs.length
  })
}

const loadPapers = () => {
  let t = savedTopifyPapers.orderBy('timeStamp', 'asc').limit(1)
  console.log(lastDoc.value)
  if (lastDoc.value) {
    t = savedTopifyPapers.startAfter(lastDoc.value)
  }
  t.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.empty)
    const _lastDoc = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
    if (_lastDoc) {
      lastDoc.value = _lastDoc
    }
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      loadingData.value = false
    }
    papersData.value = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data()
      const id = doc.id
      loadingData.value = false
      return { id, ...data }
    })
    papersDataLength.value = papersData.value.length
  })
}
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: You already said it: Firestore doesn't allow that.  You have to read all the documents up to the offset.  There isn't a workaround.

Comment: @DougStevenson `offset()` method is removed from firebase i guess.